# Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE with variable name

Tags: regex, perl

I have perl variable *bestphone* defined with the following line:

```
my $bestphone = (sort {$targets{$b} <=> $targets{$a}} keys %targets)[0];
```

When this variable is (, i get error for the following line:

```
if ((@thing == 1)&&($thing[0] =~ /return '$bestphone';/)) {
```

with the error:

> Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/return '( <-- HERE ';/
>   at

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What on earth is `$thing[0] =~ /return '$bestphone'/;/)` supposed to do? It has 3 slashes `/`, which is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) to escape the special characters in `$bestphone`.

For example:

```
$thing[0] =~ /return '\Q$bestphone\E';/
```

Comment: @Biffen I thought `\Q..\E` was the same as using qutometa?

Comment: @Biffen `perl -E '$s=q{\Q\E}; say quotemeta $s; say "\Q$s\E"'` both give output: `\\Q\\E`

Comment: @Biffen: *"Also proves quotemeta isn't the same as \Q…\E"*  I don't understand you. `quotemeta` and `\Q...\E` produce identical results, and you say that proves they are not the same? Please explain. [perldoc -f quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) says ***This is the internal function implementing the \Q escape in double-quoted strings***, so I suggest that you're mistaken

Comment: @Biffen: I don't understand why you would expect that. Both `quotemeta` and `\Q...\E` escape any non-word characters, so they both escape the backslashes and return `\\Q\\E`. There is no way to pass a parameter to `\Q\E` except by interpolating a scalar variable, but I assure you they're the *same thing*. As [**Håkon Hægland** has shown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430773/unmatched-in-regex-marked-by-here-with-variable-name/34431692?noredirect=1#comment56605273_34431692), if `$s = '\Q\E'` then `quotemeta($s)` and `"\Q$s\E"` are both equal to the string `\\Q\\E`

Answer (score -1):

Please remove the "/" after the ";" 
$besrphone=quotemeta $bestphone
and try again

Comment: Oh ";"shall also be removed